# ¿Como crear un campo calculado en una tabla de MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

soy algo nuevo utilizando MySQL, lo que quiero saber es como puedo declarar un campo calculado dentro de una tabla de MYSQL. Lo que quiero hacer es un campo calculado que calcule las horas totales trabajadas por un empleado, tengo un campo horaInicio y horaSalida pero tambien necesito un campo horasTotales que ya este dentro de la tabla.

De momento quisiera hacer algo como lo siguiente:

```
Create table Record(
    RecordID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    RecordDate DATE NOT NULL,
    EntryTime TIME NOT NULL,
    ExitTime TIME,
    TotalHours as TIME_DIFF(EntryTime, ExitTime)
)
```

Si alguien ha hecho algo similar estaría agradecido de su respuesta, he visto que se pueden tener los campos calculados en las tablas y es la única forma en la que he visto que se puede sacar una diferencia entre dos valores de tiempo, desconozco si tengo algún error de sintaxis o estoy haciendo algo mal, gracias de antemano!

Comment: Hasta donde alcanza mi conocimiento sobre lo que preguntas, una cosa es calcular el valor de un campo e insertarlo en la tabla, y la otra es esperar que ese campo sea siempre calculado en función de otros campos de la misma fila de la tabla.  Lo primero no es problema. Lo segundo ni idea, creo que se puede hacer con [TRIGGERS](https://openwebinars.net/blog/triggers-en-mysql/) supongo, pero eso escapa a mi saber. No se si es adecuado hacerlo tampoco o realizar el cálculo al extraer los datos sobre los cuales calcularlo. Una BD no es una hoja de cálculo en sí.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Puedes usar `GENERATED ALWAYS AS`, algo como

```sql
Create table Record(
    RecordID INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    RecordDate DATE NOT NULL,
    EntryTime TIME NOT NULL,
    ExitTime TIME,
    TotalHours INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS TIME_DIFF(EntryTime, ExitTime)
)
```

Si quieres que mysql guarde el valor debes agregar a la definición `STORED`

```sql
TotalHours INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS TIME_DIFF(EntryTime, ExitTime) STORED
```

**Actualización**
Mysql tiene dos formas de manejar este tipo de columnas:

- `VIRTUAL` significa que cada vez que lees el registro/fila, el valor es calculado, util si quieres ahorrar espacio, el pero es que utiliza más procesamiento pues siempre se debe realizar el cálculo
- `STORED` significa que cada vez que el registro/fila es actualizado, el valor es calculado, el pero es que utilizas espacio, la inserción es un poco más lenta (porque tiene que hacer el cálculo), la ventaja, el obtener el registro es un poco más rápido dado que el valor se había calculado previamente

Comment: Gracias por el aporte, no tenia ni idea que eso existia. :-)

Comment: Hasta hace unos minutos yo tampoco lo sabía...

Comment: @Aguardientico, algo importante es que sobre campos `STORED` se puede crear indices, cosa que en `VIRTUAL` (_valor por defecto_) no

Comment: Muchas gracias, estoy utilizando MySQL en consola y solo tuve que cambiar un poco la sintaxis pero tu respuesta me dio justo la ayuda que necesitaba, gracias por tu aporte!